# 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process' in discrord.py

Tags: discord.py

im have a problem. Its my code python, discord-bot.

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.reply("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
        return
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = await channel.connect()
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Path_Program/ffmpeg.exe", source=r"example.mp3"))
```

The bot connects to the voice channel, but gives the following error

```
Ignoring exception in command join:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 178, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\HoDeC-bot\bot.py", line 64, in join
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/Path_Program/ffmpeg.exe", source=r"example.mp3"))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 312, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 165, in __init__
    self._process: subprocess.Popen = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 185, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(f"{executable} was not found.") from None
discord.errors.ClientException: C:/Path_Program/ffmpeg.exe was not found.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 950, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 187, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: C:/Path_Program/ffmpeg.exe was not found.
Exception ignored in: <function AudioSource.__del__ at 0x000001D17D222B00>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 115, in __del__
    self.cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 245, in cleanup
    self._kill_process()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\player.py", line 194, in _kill_process
    proc = self._process
AttributeError: 'FFmpegPCMAudio' object has no attribute '_process'
```

ffmpeg true.
Help me pls, idk.

I tried reinstalling ffmpeg, me syntax and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I didn't have it installed ffmpeg.exe

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).